# Input and multiline text in the same div - alignment

Tags: html, css

Consider following html:

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id felis nulla. Nulla facilisi. Nam pretium elit arcu, et laoreet felis consequat et. Suspendisse id diam ut nisi congue imperdiet. Nulla gravida consequat ante id vulputate. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
</div>
```

Is there a way to align all the rows the same, without changing HTML, but only with CSS?

Comment: What do you mean with "align all the rows the same". I see no rows here...

Comment: I see no effort to accomplish your goal. Please revise with more code.

Comment: I would advice to use label instead of div to make the text clickable as well. That will improve UX.

Comment: @Vi100 you see no rows? As in physical, visible, rows, not rows in HTML? Too bad.

Comment: @brynzovskii I asked in the question: "without changing HTML". If I could change HTML, I would just wrap the text around span or label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the type of thing you mean?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id felis nulla. Nulla facilisi. Nam pretium elit arcu, et laoreet felis consequat et. Suspendisse id diam ut nisi congue imperdiet. Nulla gravida consequat ante id vulputate. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
</div>
```